# Why is the presence of a SizedBox moves the siblings in a Stack?

Tags: flutter, widget, transform

I am struggling with the way Flutter handles Widget positioning.

The context: my goal is to layout an animated scene with a moving vehicle and a gas pump; depending on the device orientation I'd like to scale and position the viewer's eye (the pump location) at the center of the screen, the same way I was doing with the native Swift version on the iPhone as follows:

Landscape mode:
[image: Landscape mode]

Portrait mode:
[image: Portrait mode]

While trying to achieve this with Flutter, I'm facing various issues, one being the fact that the presence of a debug widget moves others widget from the same Stack:

It's centered with the SizedBox in the stack…
[image: Centered with brown Sizebox]

But it's no more without it:
[image: No longer entered with the absence of the SizedBox]

My code is as follows and a minimal darted version can be found right here: https://dartpad.dev/?id=ccd214b1efacb61b158f6f0c2092e809

```dart
Widget buildScene(Size size, /* double scale,*/ bool debug) {
    final hill = Hill(size: size);

    final punmpOffsetX = size.width / 4;

    // == Build the scene
    return Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.none, children: [
      // == The whole scene debug materialisation 
      if (debug). => THIS IS WHAT I TOGGLE WHICH MOVES THE REST OF THE SCENE
      SizedBox(
          width: size.width,
          height: size.height,
          child: Container(
            color: const Color(0x7ff67e22),
          )),

      // == Add the sky
      ...widget.clouds,

      // == Add ground
      hill,

      // == The pump
      Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(punmpOffsetX /*- 115 / 2*/, 120),
          child: Container(
              width: 150,
              child: ScaleTransition(
                  scale: Tween<double>(begin: 3, end: 1).animate(
                      CurvedAnimation(
                          parent: _controller, curve: Curves.elasticOut)),
                  child: Pump(offset: Offset.zero, width: 150)))),

      // == The animated vehicle
      DrivingVehicle(hill: hill),
```

Comment: post the minimal, reproducible code example (without any external dependencies) showing your issue

Comment: @pskink Find the minimal ex right in there https://dartpad.dev/?id=ccd214b1efacb61b158f6f0c2092e809

Comment: try `fit: StackFit.expand` - the default is `loose`

Comment: @pskink Alas, that stretches the whole widgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution which consists of using Positioned() Widget to absolute position Widget. Transform.translate adds a translation to the widget current position within the rendering flow, this is why the removal of a Widget made the remaining ones move.

The code becomes:

```
    // == Build the scene
    return Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.none, children: [
      // == The whole scene debug materialisation 
      if (debug)
      Positioned(left: 0, top: 0, child: SizedBox(
          width: size.width,
          height: size.height,
          child: Container(
            color: const Color(0x7ff67e22),
          ))),

    
      // == Add ground
      Positioned(left: 0, top: 0, child: hill),

      // == The pump
      Positioned(left: punmpOffsetX, top: 120, child: 
          offset: Offset(punmpOffsetX /*- 115 / 2*/, 120),
          child: Container(
              width: 150,
              child: ScaleTransition(
                  scale: Tween<double>(begin: 3, end: 1).animate(
                      CurvedAnimation(
                          parent: _controller, curve: Curves.elasticOut)),
                  child: Pump(offset: Offset.zero, width: 150)))),

      // == The animated vehicle
      Positioned(left: 0, top: 0, child: DrivingVehicle(hill: hill)),
```